# About unique=True and (unique=True, index=True) in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I create tables use flask-sqlalchemy like this:

```
class Te(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tt'
    id = Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    t1 = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, )
    t3 = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, index=True, )
```

and In my Sequel Pro , I get the table create info:

```
CREATE TABLE `tt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t3` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `t1` (`t1`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_tt_t3` (`t3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

this means t1 is entirely same as t3 in MySQL? So when you define `unique=True`, it's not require to define `index=True`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have a term confusion with the index purpose in sqlalchemy. In sql databases index are used speed up query performance.

According to the sqlalchemy documentation of [defining constraints and indexes.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html)

You would notice the use of the index key because the sql code generated is:

```
UNIQUE KEY `ix_tt_t3` (`t3`)
```

The way how sqlalchemy nouns the index is `idx_%columnlabbel`. And that matches with the sql code generated.

So the use or not of index it is only related with performance and the unique key means that the column values cannot be repeated all along of the same column in the 'tt' table.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for help. I ask this question because I guess when the database create unique constraints, it should create an index behind. When a new value insert, the database should search exists values is equal new value or not. If haven`t an index, the search process may too slow?

Comment: In order to simplify the answer i would say:
When you querys a table by using their PK atribute then, generally, the query performance is quite fast. But when you starts to increace the number of filters using some other atributes of the table, the query needs time to process. Because the term of "performance" would depends on your metrics objectives, rather tan to set indexes all other columns or just some. I would recomend  to put them as soon your querys starts to become slow to your aplication if, after a small analisys, the problems belongs to the querys access of  that table.

Comment: @LucasPC So do you suggest using index=True when that column is going to used a lot for referencing in many queries?

Comment: The purpose of "index" is to allow fast lookups for the rows with the corresponding column values. So yes, I do suggest so.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required. A *unique constraint* is more often than not implemented using a *unique index*, but you need not care about that detail, if all you want is uniqueness.